# How to disable Ctrl+P so that user can not directly print the currently opened document?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript

While working in Lotusscript, I want my users not to be able to print the documents by pressing ctrl+p. Instead of this, i provide an action button, so that it makes some extra steps before printing the document. Is this possible to disable direct printing (ctrl+p) using lotusscript or java. Or as an alternate is it possible that we could capture the ctrl+p event so that we may add our code before the real printing goes on.

I'm using Release 9.0.1FP8

Comment: If you are worried about the users might print by mistake, just go to control panel, and set the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer as default printer. If this is not available, just search for a free pdf printer and set it as default.

Answer (score 4):

Add a computed field called $KeepPrivate with a value of "1". This fields prevents the user from using CTRL+P.

Then add your own button with the following logic:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    Set doc = uidoc.Document
    Call doc.RemoveItem("$KeepPrivate")
    Call doc.Save(True,True)
    doc.SaveOptions = "0"
    Call uidoc.Close
    Set uidoc = ws.EditDocument(True,doc,False) 
    Call uidoc.Print
    Dim item As New NotesItem(doc,"$KeepPrivate","1")
    Call uidoc.Save
    Call doc.Save(True,True)
    doc.SaveOptions = "0"

End Sub
```

This button will change the value of the $KeepPrivate field behind-the-scenes and show the print dialog.

Comment: @Tschallacka I updated my answer with a specific solution